# Should I use Unique releaseId in each KieFileSystem?

Tags: drools, rule-engine, kie

We are recently started supporting parallel requests in our RuleEngine. Total of 4 threads and each thread handles a request to get or save rules. Previously, we were using default release ID and static constant source filename in KieFileSystem and since the requests were handled sequentially, it did not cause any issue.

Now, for each request, I am generating a unique releaseId and writing to KieFileSystem, like so:

```
String uniqueSourceFilename = generateUniqueSourceFilename(namespace);
        ReleaseId releaseId = kieServices.newReleaseId(RELEASE_ID_GROUP, uniqueSourceFilename, RELEASE_ID_VERSION);
        kieFileSystem.generateAndWritePomXML(releaseId);

kieFileSystem.write(kieResources.newInputStreamResource(ruleFile)
                        .setSourcePath(uniqueSourceFilename)
                        .setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL));

final KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem).buildAll();
final KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(releaseId);

return kContainer.newStatelessKieSession();
```

Since this change, we have started observing that the heap memory usage has started increasing steadily (Heap set at 2GB). I read that the stateless session does not require to be disposed off (after we call execute on it) explicitly.

Is there a possibility of objects (kiefilesystem, kiemodule or kiecontainer) still remaining in memory even after GC? Can I explicitly delete/remove these objects after I execute rules in the session?

And do I even need to have a unique releaseId for each KieFileSystem/KieModule (even if they are on different threads)?

Comment: Interesting question. Have you tried to profile it with JVisual VM? An Heap dump will give you precise evidence if some of the objects are still allocated. Let us know

Comment: So, I recently came across a discussion that mentioned that KieContainers (like Statefull sessions) also need to be disposed off. I am currently investigating if that might be the cause of issue here, since I am creating a container in each request but not really disposing it explicitly anywhere.